# ggplot2 histogram discrepancy

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using Hands On Programming With R (Grolemund), and I'm stuck on the basic part about histograms using ggplot2

*R-Studio Version 1.3.1073*

*ggplot2 Version 3.3.5*

The code is:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
qplot(x, binwidth = 1)
```

And it looks like:

[image]

It **should** look like this:
[Screenshot from the book, left-hand histogram is the relevant one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dqv4.png)

[image]

So essentially it's centering each datapoint differently. In the book, variable 1 is displayed as 1-2, but in my version, variable 1 is 0.5 - 1.5, and so on.

Does anyone know why they differ like this, and how to correct it to what's in the book, as this is more consistent with how I need data to be handled?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi alice. This is probably a change in ggplot2 which occurred somewhere in the past (according to the book's GitHub repo it was last updated about three years ago). To replicate the figure in the book you could do `qplot(x, breaks = 0:4, closed = "left")`

Comment: @stefan - thank you! that works fine, and I know I have more to learn about the various arguments of ggplot2, however, I would now query how to know what values to put for `breaks = ` in a larger dataset? With the older format from the OP, this didn't need to be specified, but with this fix it does.

Comment: (: Yep. Depends on the data. For the nice integer vectors used in the book you could  use something like `breaks = seq(min(x) - 1, max(x) + 1)`. But that's still not a solution for more general cases.